# can't resolve app.module.ngfactory when using yarn webpack:prod

Tags: angular5, jhipster

In my application, the front-end and back-end are separated, get this issue when I issue:

```
yarn webpack:prod
```

to generate a front-end package for production. however:

```
yarn start
```

works fine.

Note:
angular version is 5.1.0
jhipter version is 4.14.3
yarn version is 1.3.2

Very appreciated for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade seems too complex, so I regenerate a new jhipster project, the angular 5.1 is upgraded to 5.2. then copy my source code to the new project.

Because @angular/http is updated to @angular/common/http, I did a lot of code change manually, and finally get it worked.